# Are there any performance differences between 32-bit vs 64-bit Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

Are there any noticeable/measureable performance increases in 64-bit Nightly (or Waterfox, or Palemoon) vs stable 32-bit Firefox - e.g., in UI responsiveness, startup times, memory efficiency, tab handling, HTML/Javascript/DOM performance, hardware acceleration, etc?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Is there a problem which this is related to? As your question is written, it may be off topic. Please read [ask] to help improve your question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it to be a little more specific/close-ended.  Hope it's suitable.

Comment: How is this 'opinion based'?  The question that was asked is 100% MEASURABLE. 

Answer (score 1):

I doubt online content does actually profit from 64bit accuracy over 32bit accuracy. You might be able to open more tabs/windows due to the 64bit version being able to go above the 32bit memory limit, but in terms of rendering speed there shouldn't be any differences between versions.

One of the Mozilla developers supported this position in an interview he once gave:

> The biggest advantage of a 64-bit browser on a 64-bit operating system
>   is that it can address more than the 4GB of memory available to a
>   32-bit application, letting users keep open hundreds of tabs without
>   crashing the browser.
>
> "It seems that there are users who regularly run into the 4GB memory
>   limits of 32-bit builds," Smedberg said in his Dec. 21 message. "These
>   users often have hundreds or even thousands of tabs. These users are
>   using the 64-bit nightlies not primarily to be part of our testing
>   community, but because those builds are the best product available."

Source: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9234997/Mozilla_compromises_on_x64_Firefox_after_user_backlash

The article makes it perfectly clear that 64bit versions of Firefox are unoptimized and never made it out of beta. It also showed that x64 versions were no priority for Mozilla, but performance has always been a priority implying that there's no practical performance benefit other than the ability to open thousands of tabs.

Comment: What about UI responsiveness, startup times, memory management, etc?

Comment: Probably it's negligible. It's hard for this kind of software to reach the 32-bit limits, even harder to profit anything from 64-bit.

Comment: @Caspid UI responsiveness and startup times - I don't see how they profit from higher accuracy. If there's an effect I haven't recognized it so far. This stuff is best enhanced with a powerful CPU, defragged hard drive, a minimum amount of addons and tabs. I addressed memory issues in my answer. If you think about Windows not limiting the app to 4MB pages in memory then yes, it runs more efficiently, but I have yet see this translate into substial differences compared to 32bit. If you can substantiate such differences then please do.